# Is it worth swapping to a faster shader for non-camera rays?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

The old trick of using 'Light Path > Is Camera Ray' as the factor for a mix between the shader seen by the camera and a simpler 'fake' shader that is never directly seen (except maybe in reflections).

For example, you could switch between a detailed Principled shader with normals and roughness, and a simple diffuse shader as a 'proxy'.

My question is... is this really even worth doing? I did a little testing once, and hardly noticed a difference in render times (not sure about memory).

Comment: "*I did a little testing once, and hardly noticed a difference*" <- There is your answer